# apt-get equivalent of yum localinstall

Tags: package-management, apt, yum

When using Fedora I usually use `yum localinstall` as a way to install a rpm obtained outside the distribution repositories. I can't find an equivalent option in the `apt-get` man page. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, if that matters.

What is the `apt-get` equivalent of `yum localinstall`? Should I use `dpkg` directly in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:
`$sudo apt install ./your_package.deb`

Comment: +1 for ``apt``. ``gdebi`` isn't available by default and ``dpkg`` will do a partial installation unless dependencies are met. ``apt`` will install unmet dependencies before installing the ``deb`` package. Tip: this also works ``sudo apt install ./your_package.deb``.

Comment: Yep, that's the right answer nowadays. Question is ten years old though and apt-get was fussy back then :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you package depends on some other packages available in repositories, the following command will take care of installing dependencies too (which `dpkg` cannot do):

```
gdebi my_local_package.deb
```

however you may need to first install `gdebi` itself, if not already available on your Debian installation.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Just note, that this requires X. It's good for workstation. Not so good for server operated remotely.

Comment: @Michał Šrajer: no, it do not need X, you talk about `gdebi-gtk`.

Comment: when trying gdebi solution, look for `gdebi-core` package for CLI only. it looks like `gdebi` is GTK by default. You can see the list of gdebi pkgs like so: `apt-cache search gdebi`. You want this one: "gdebi-core - simple tool to install deb files".

Comment: If I have `gdebi` and `apt` installed on my laptop together, would they share the same configuration files? Assuming I use `apt` to install some packages, would `gdebi` know it?

Answer (score 10):

As said @enzotib, `gdebi` is nice, it even allows simple inspection of pre/post install script if your are a paranoid like me.

But don't forget the shell way, little padawan.

In a shell, "simply":

```
dpkg -i file.deb
```

If all dependencies are present, it will install. Else you will see an ugly and long error message but this is not the end of the world:

```
# dpkg -i somepackage.deb 
...snip...
dpkg: error processing somepackage (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 somepackage
```

Now, either install the missing dependencies or revert:

```
# apt-get install -f
...snip...
The following extra packages will be installed:
...snip...
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use dpkg directly:

```
dpkg -i my_local_package.deb
```

or setup your own local repository. I prefer to do just `dpkg -i`.

Comment: Is this the preferred way to do that on Debian-based distribution? On Fedora and RHEL I always use `yum` and never touch `rpm` directly.

Comment: I think it's fine. From official docs: "dpkg is a command-line tool used to install packages".

Comment: As a note for future googlers, this answer will fail if the new package depends on other packages which are not already installed. `dpkg` checks dependencies, but does not fetch them, that's why `apt` and `gdebi` were made.